# Omega - Debugging blocks only for specified role

Tags: 7, blocks, users, theming, debugging

Is it possible to see debugging blocks only for specified role?

**IDEA**
I made special role "*theme developer*" to see debugging blocks of Omega only for this role. When I check in *admin/appearance/settings/my_subtheme -> Debbugging* options:

- *Enable the debugging (placeholder) blocks for the selected roles.*
- *Enable the grid overlay for the selected roles.*

and select "*theme developer*" role debugging blocks will be seen by granted users only.

**PROBLEM**
If I am an administrator I can see debugging blocks even if I'm not in "theme developer" role. Why?

After documentation http://drupal.org/node/1298690 it should work as I wrote in idea but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're user uid=1 (administrator), you'll see everything regardless of role. You may be confusing it with the "administrator" role, which is not the same as the admin user.

Comment: It can be for uid=1 (for me shouldn't) but I wrote "administrator" not uid=1 or admin user. I know the diffrence.